# MySql Update takes very long

Tags: mysql

I found a strange behavior on following query:

```
UPDATE llx_socpeople SET no_email=1 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT source_id FROM llx_mailing_cibles where tag = "68d74c3bc618ebed67919ed5646d0ffb");
```

takes 1 min and 30 seconds.

When I split up the commands to 2 queries:

```
SELECT source_id FROM llx_mailing_cibles where tag = "68d74c3bc618ebed67919ed5646d0ffb";
```

Result is 10842

```
UPDATE llx_socpeople SET no_email=1 WHERE rowid = 10842;
```

Result is shown in milliseconds.

Table llx_socpeople has about 7.000 records, llx_mailing_cibles has about 10.000 records.

MySQL Version is: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

I already tried to optimize/repair both tables with no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: because the 1st method pointlessly executes a subquery for every row of the main query? so, dupe of [MySQL subquery slows down drastically, but they work fine independently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/mysql-subquery-slows-down-drastically-but-they-work-fine-independently)

Comment: try `WHERE rowid = ` instead of `WHERE rowid IN `

Comment: Thanks for the fast response - solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as the subquery is being run for each row of the main query, we can expect a longer execution time.
What I would suggest would be to rely on a inner join for performing the update:

```
UPDATE llx_socpeople AS t1
INNER JOIN llx_mailing_cibles AS t2
ON t1.rowid = t2.source_id
SET t1.no_email=1 
WHERE t2.tag = "68d74c3bc618ebed67919ed5646d0ffb";
```

This way you will definitely get far better performance.

You can troubleshoot your slow queries using the EXPLAIN MySql statement. Find more details about it on [it's dedicated page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) from the official documentation. It might help you discover any missing indexes.

Comment: Thanks - solved my problem. This works if there is more then 1 result in the subquery